# Simple login function to check length of input and not an integer

Tags: python

Python newbie here, I am trying to create a simple login function that checks if the user's input is more than 3 characters and that it also doesn't contain a number.

The function does sort of work, because while if the user enters less than 3 characters it prints 'Your name must be more than 3 characters'.

What I can't figure out is how to check if the user enters a number then print 'Must not contain numbers'.

```
def login_function():
    print('****************************************')
    user_name = ""
    while len(user_name) <= 3: 
        user_name = input('Please enter your name: ')
        print('Your name must be more than 3 characters')
    return user_name

login_function()
```

I have tried using `str(input(''))` to  make sure that the user only enters a character. I have also tried `if` `else` but it ended up quite messy.

Comment: Are you aware of how to use `re.find` of the regex module?

Comment: You should also move the error above your input for a better user experience

Comment: Use re.findall: `import re
while True: 
    user_name = input('Please enter your name: ')
    if len(user_name) <= 3:
        print('Your name must be more than 3 characters')
    elif re.findall(r'\d', user_name):
        print('Your name must not contain any digits')
    else:
        break
`

Comment: @OneCricketeer no I don't know the regex module, I am not that advanced with Python yet. My question has been closed because it's similar to another question but the answers don't make sense to me

Comment: @TimurShtatland Thanks, that works nearly as intended but it doesn't work for when I enter a digit, it still prints `'Your name must be more than 3 characters'` `instead of 'Your name must not contain any digits'`

Comment: @trombonee You can reverse the order of the conditions in the `if...elif ...else` statement, and make the test for digits the **first** test.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Thank you, that has worked perfectly.

Comment: You're asking how to check if a string contains a digit, and so does the other post. Can you clarify which answers don't make sense? If you're confused on usage of functions, refer to the Python documentation